# How to make default incremental value by some constant, in enum

Tags: c#, enums

How can I make  `enum` variable's to be incremented in a certain [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)?

For instance:

```
enum Days {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

Now the values will be incremented by 1. How can I increment the values, let’s say by_ 2? Something like:

```
enum Days {Sat=2, Sun=4, Mon=6, Tue=8, Wed=10, Thu=12, Fri=14};
```

Do I have to do this manually for each and every element?

Comment: Yes you have to do it manually but you could always be clever and write a simple console application to take in a string, split it on commas then join it back together with the input values, then paste this back into your code.

Comment: Are you doing this so frequently that it's becoming a problem or are you just curious?

Comment: @CBauer Just curious.Would you like to elaborate what kind of problems ?Global constants ?

Comment: @Sayse If you're clever enough, you'll write T4 template for code generation :)

Comment: I mean are you creating a large number of enumerations that defining the progressions are taking considerable amounts of time for you? The concept of an enum is a compile-time constant stand-in for "magic numbers" in your code, so asking a questions such as "how can I make enums increment via arithmetic progression" indicates you may be using them for the wrong purpose.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - If I'm even cleverer than that I would make it so that future developers don't need to care about it :)

Comment: Unfortunately, enum types cannot be created on custom value types, as such you have to do this manually.

It would be nice if we could create a custom value type, called something like "ULongBitValue" that is a struct.  Then say  enum SomeBitFlag : ULongBitValue.  Then we could write implicit operators for it so that 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, always returns 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.

Comment: If you have a custom database with values like that and you want to map to poco's etc, you could look at PetaPoco.  It comes with T4 Templates that will generate all of your pocos from an existing database for you just by saving the T4 template in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in practice you would have to do it manually -- but do you *really* need to do so?

Enums that are not decorated with `FlagsAttribute` should not need to have specific values assigned to each member because the primary purpose of an enum is to distinguish among a specific set of items, and not necessarily map those items to a specific value. Depending on what you need the numbers for, it is quite possible that using a mapping solution external to the enum would be better software engineering.

Theoretically you can also use a [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to do this programmatically; you would be writing a little code that generates the desired source code automatically from your own viewpoint, but this is overkill for such a simple scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend staying away from this approach, where data is stored with enumerated values.  Instead, keep the enum simple and use it for its designed purpose: a enumeration of named values.  Then store data elsewhere, using something like an interpreter or mediator pattern to access and modify the data on the fly.  One approach is to use a set or dictionary where the keys are the enum values and the values are your numbers.